# v-date-picker double click date selection issue

Tags: vue.js, vcalendar

I am using **https://vcalendar.io/** library to display date picker in my vuejs application.
I am using below version

```
"v-calendar": "^1.0.8",
```

popover is opened on textbox click, Issue is when i perform double click to select date then its not selecting date, it deselect and close popover

check link for issue: *https://vcalendar.io/datepicker.html#date*

Please help me to select date value on double click

Comment: so is the popover opening on double click?

Comment: @Amaarrockz once popover is opend, issue is when user double click on date for selection then date is not selecting and it close popover without selecting date.

Comment: Please share your code?

Comment: it was working fine when I added "is-required".
`<vc-date-picker mode='single' v-model="newListing.purchase_date"  *is-required* :disabledDates='[{ start: Date.now() }]' />`